# Android How do I read users dictionary to scan for words?

Tags: android, dictionary

I'm writig a program to help with scrabble. I want to harness the user dictionary to scan through. How do I access this file to scan through?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to query UserDictionary content provider on Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8282017/how-to-query-userdictionary-content-provider-on-android)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will want to use the [UserDictionary](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/UserDictionary.html) class.

Here is one example: [How to query UserDictionary content provider on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8282017/1267661)

Here is some Android documentation: [Content Provider Basics](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics.html) (It uses the UserDictionary as the example ContentProvider, which is perfect for your question.)

Comment: Why do you need a content provider? User protecting from the application?

Comment: Basically a ContentProvider is Android's standardized way accessing system databases. They are easy enough to use and less "dangerous" than allowing any app to run SQL commands.

Comment: The UserDictionary only provides user defined words, doesn't it? Are there no standard dictionaries that come with Android?