# Performing 'like' queries in Android Content Provider

Tags: java, android

I'm implementing a Content Provider on Android. I'd like my query to look for more than just exact matches--is there a way to specify a 'like' query in the content provider query method?

Current code. Note that `mSearchString` is a string the user provides--I'm currently using it to query the `UserDictionary`, and the only way it returns anything is if `mSearchString` exactly matches a word in the `UserDictionary`. I'd like to be able to match partial queries (for instance, if apple, aunt and practical are in the dictionary, I'd like to search for "a" and return them all).

```
        mSelectionClause = UserDictionary.Words.WORD + " = ?";

        // Moves the user's input string to the selection arguments.
        // Remember to add code here to check for invalid or malicious input.
        mSelectionArgs[0] = mSearchString;

    // Does a query against the table and returns a Cursor object
            Cursor mCursor = getContentResolver().query(
                    UserDictionary.Words.CONTENT_URI,  // The content URI of the words table
                    mProjection,                       // The columns to return for each row
                    mSelectionClause,                   // Either null, or the word the user entered
                    mSelectionArgs,                    // Either empty, or the string the user entered
                    mSortOrder);
```

Comment: "I'm implementing a Content Provider on Android" -- your code looks a lot more like you are trying to *use* a `ContentProvider` written by somebody else. Are you trying to actually *implement* your *own* `ContentProvider`?

Comment: According to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30220387/1015327), at least for the `UserDictionary`, `like ?` should actually work.

Comment: Hanno - like ? in conjunction with wrapping the user's input with %..% worked. And a shout out to CommonsWare for keeping me honest with precise wording, too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am using `SQLiteDatabase` (not using `getContentResolver()` and I don't know what it is), but I can search for words `like` a given pattern (named `pattern`) using this code, so since the syntax looks the same, I imagine it could work for you:

```
    String whereClause = "word like ?";
    String[] wildCardReplacements = {pattern};
    cursor = database.query(TABLE_NAME, mColumns, whereClause,  
             wildCardReplacements, null, null, null);
```

So if `pattern` contains `%a%`, I'd get "apple, aunt, and, practical" and lots of others.

In case it's not obvious, in your case, something like `mSearchString = "%" + mSearchString + "%"` would allow user to merely enter `a` (for example) and get the desired matches.

P.S. `database` is defined as an `android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase`.

Comment: Awesome DSlomer64, thanks - your answer was entirely correct.

Comment: Really glad I could help.=

Answer (score 4):

> 100% working code, Change to your code (cursor) this like,

```
Cursor contactsContractContacts = resolver.query(
ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, projection,
ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " like ?",
new String[]{"%" + filterStr + "%"},
ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");
```