# Search for text which contains certain character in SearchView AutoCompleteTextView

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, searchview

I am trying to modify an [open source dictionary project](https://bitbucket.org/raymanzhang/mdict-android-opensource) which use `ActionBarSherlock` `SearchView$SearchAutoComplete`. For example, I have an entry called "Google Play". The `SearchView` is able to return suggestion when I type "Google", but that is not the case if I search "Play". How to enable the `SearchView` to be able to search entry which contains the text?

```
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            if (MdxDictBase.isMdxCmd(newText)){
                currentEntry.setEntryNo(DictEntry.kSystemCmdEntryNo);
            }
            if (!skipUpdateEntryList) {
                dict.locateFirst(newText, true, true, true, false, currentEntry);
                syncHeadwordList();
            }
            skipUpdateEntryList = false;
            return true; //return false if want the system provide a suggestion list?
        }
```

The complete code can be [found here](https://bitbucket.org/raymanzhang/mdict-android-opensource/src/eba7b9b4ead17a5b3e027da4a37dbd4ee1162596/src/cn/mdict/fragments/DictView.java?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default).

And this is the `Cursor` query which I [found from here](https://bitbucket.org/raymanzhang/mdict-android-opensource/src/eba7b9b4ead17a5b3e027da4a37dbd4ee1162596/src/cn/mdict/DictContentProvider.java?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default).

```
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Got query:" + uri.toString());
        if (uri.getPath() != null && uri.getPath().startsWith(SEARCH_PATH)) {
            if (fCurrentDict != null && fCurrentDict.isValid()) {
                String query=uri.getLastPathSegment();
                if (query!=null && query.length()>0){
                    DictEntry entry = new DictEntry(0, "", fCurrentDict.getDictPref().getDictId());
                    if (query != null && query.length() > 0)
                        fCurrentDict.locateFirst(query, true, false, true, false, entry);
                    if (entry.isValid()) {
                        String limit = uri.getQueryParameter(SearchManager.SUGGEST_PARAMETER_LIMIT);
                        int maxResultCount = 20;
                        if (limit != null && limit.length() > 0) {
                            try {
                                maxResultCount = Integer.parseInt(limit);
                            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                        ArrayList<DictEntry> entryList = new ArrayList<DictEntry>();
                        fCurrentDict.getEntries(entry, maxResultCount, entryList);
                        String[] columns = new String[]{
                                BaseColumns._ID,
                                SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_1,
                                SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_DATA_ID,
                                SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_SHORTCUT_ID};
                        MatrixCursor cursor = new MatrixCursor(columns, maxResultCount);
                        Object[] row;
                        for (DictEntry cur_entry : entryList) {
                            String intentDataId = String.format("%d_%d_%s", cur_entry.getDictId(), cur_entry.getEntryNo(), cur_entry.getHeadword());
                            row = new Object[]{cur_entry.hashCode(), cur_entry.getHeadword(), intentDataId, SearchManager.SUGGEST_NEVER_MAKE_SHORTCUT};
                            cursor.addRow(row);
                        }
                        return cursor;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

This is the `locateFirst` method which I [found from here](https://bitbucket.org/raymanzhang/mdict-android-opensource/src/eba7b9b4ead17a5b3e027da4a37dbd4ee1162596/src/cn/mdict/mdx/MdxDictBase.java?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default).

```
/**
     * Locates the first entry that match the specified headword
     *
     * @param headword     Headword to be searched for
     * @param convertKey   Convert the given headword into different Chinese form according to dictionary settings?
     * @param partialMatch Match partial of the headword. For example "abc" can be matched with "abd" headword search
     * @param entry        The matched entry if found
     * @return Return kMdxSuccess when succeed, otherwise return error codes.
     */
    public synchronized int locateFirst(String headword, boolean convertKey, boolean partialMatch, boolean startWithMatch, boolean bestMatch, DictEntry entry) {
        if (isValid()) {
            return locateFirstN(headword, convertKey, partialMatch, startWithMatch, bestMatch, entry);
        } else {
            return kMdxDatabaseNotInited;
        }
    }
```

This is the adapter which I believe is responsible to display the list of suggestion:
https://bitbucket.org/raymanzhang/mdict-android-opensource/src/eba7b9b4ead17a5b3e027da4a37dbd4ee1162596/src/cn/mdict/widgets/MdxAdapter.java?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default

Comment: The code you've posted do not show any signs of filtering. There should be a class or some code that does the filtering based on an input string from the `searchView`. Look for code that gets the string from the `searchView` and passes it as search query, probably inside a `onTextChanged` callback, and post it's code and any code related to it to further help you.

Comment: Add your code of search . Its not sufficient code .

Comment: I have edited my question.

Comment: Well i think you should use a RegEx to query Content provider similar to (% WildCard). I guess you have no control on query cause its part of the library.So when you are passing the query string to CP first make it a pattern.  Exa :- to pass "br"  -> [[a-z]*br[a-z]*] . I am not sure but i think its worth a try .

Comment: @ADM , do you have any example of implementation?

Comment: But your case is different . You are relying on a library i guess where you only can handle the selection Args . So RegEx can be a solution see  [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33286302/performing-like-queries-in-android-content-provider).

Comment: After testing, I found that only changes in `onQueryTextChange(String newText)` will affect the search suggestion. No effect seen for `Cursor query`. Is it mean I need to make `String newText` as pattern? How to do that?

Comment: Use as i suggested above . Putt your `String`  between Regex.  [[a-z]*word[a-z]*] . let me know if it works.

Comment: @ADM, I do not know how to put string between Regex. I am a self learner and has limited knowledge.

Comment: Just use simple concatenate with + operator . I am not sure whether it will work or not .. but if you read the link I have attached above seems a right way ..

Comment: I tried `String que =  "[[a-z]*" + query + "[a-z]*]"; displayByHeadword(que, false);` but this is not working.

Answer (score -1):

on TextChanged event use .Contains method of Strings. And then perform your required search on basis of that method. I hope this will help you